# Let $f$ be a continuous, show that there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that for all x with $|x|<\varepsilon$ we have $f(x)>\dfrac12$.

Tags: calculus, limits

> Let $f$ be a continuous function on $(−1, 1)$ with $f(0)=1$. Show that there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that for all x with $|x|<\varepsilon$ we have $f(x)>\dfrac12$.

I have with me the 'solution' but I'm not able to follow it at all. I won't be surprised if it is wrong either as the book is full of errors. If someone could please help we with the scratch-work along with the proof it would be very helpful.

Comment: $f$ is continuous, so there is an $\epsilon > 0$ such that $\lvert x-0\rvert = \lvert x\rvert < \epsilon$ implies that $\lvert f(x)-f(0)\rvert = \lvert f(x)-1\rvert < \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: If you look at the answers given here you should also be convinced that the problem statement holds true even if the number $1/2$ of the problem is replaced by any number less than $1$ (for example $9/10$ or $\sqrt{2}-1$). This is an essential point one must understand.

Comment: There are many equivalent ways to define continuity of a real function at a point. Which one are you using?

Answer (score 2):

This follows immediately
from the definition of continuity.

$f$ is continuous at $a$
if
$\lim_{x \to a} f(x)
=f(a)
$.

Going a level deeper,
this means that
for any $\delta > 0$
there is an $\epsilon > 0$
such that
$|x-a| < \epsilon
\implies |f(x)-f(a)| < \delta
$.

Now choose $\delta = \frac12$
and $a = 1$.

This says that
there is an $\epsilon > 0$
such that
$|x-1| < \epsilon
\implies |f(x)-f(1)| < \frac12
$.

Since
$f(1) = 1$,
this says
$|x-1| < \epsilon
\implies -\frac12 <  f(x)-1 < \frac12
$
which is the same as
$ \frac12 < f(x) < \frac32
$.